# Facebook FQL batch requests: suddenly receiving "Exception: 1: An unknown error occurred"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Up until yesterday (June 20, 2012) my application was running smoothly. As of yesterday, I started receiving this error on literally ALL multiqueries to various pages (but curiously not to the active user).

I'm really not sure what other information to provide besides the fact that this application is querying a single days worth of information from the 'insights' table as well as a few other metrics from other tables... but that has never been a problem for me.

I've looked at a few bug reports but nothing seems to mimic the issue I'm having. There's sporadic reports of this error happening throughout the month, but it must not be rampant because it doesn't seem of high concern to Facebook.

Any ideas?

Comment: FQL query for page_fans_city is giving me a 500 Internal Server Error response. Bug!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, removing `page_fans_city` from the list of metrics I wanted made everything work again. Hope that helps you.